# how to get data from my List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf

guyz i know how to add data from my list but the problem is how can i retrieve it...?

id delcared my list in GlobalVar.cs:

```
public static List<string> ViolationRefNumToPrint = new List<string>();
```

here's the code behind in adding data to my list.....

```
    GlobalVar.ViolationRefNumToPrint.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < lvviolations.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        GlobalVar.ViolationRefNumToPrint.Add(((EmpViolationObject)lvviolations.Items[i]).VioRefNum);
    }
```

my question is how can i retrieve it to my list... :(

## **EDIT**

guyz i've used the code below. which is given by @evanmcdonnal. actually i'm goin to use this on my report... and i've used **DocumentViewer**

here's my code....

```
        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

        string ats = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(ats.ToString() + @"\Template\ReportViolation.xaml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

        reportDocument.XamlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reportDocument.XamlImagePath = Path.Combine(ats.ToString(), @"Template\");
        reader.Close();


        DateTime dateTimeStart = DateTime.Now; // start time measure here
        List<ReportData> listData = new List<ReportData>();
        int i = 0;

        foreach (string item in GlobalVar.ViolationRefNumToPrint)
        {
            ReportData data = new ReportData();

            data.ReportDocumentValues.Add("PrintDate", DateTime.Now); 
            data.ReportDocumentValues.Add("EmpIDNum", NewIDNumber.ToString()); 
            data.ReportDocumentValues.Add("EmpName", NewEmpName.ToString()); 
            data.ReportDocumentValues.Add("EmpPosition", NewPosition.ToString()); 

            data.ReportDocumentValues.Add("PageNumber",(i + 1)); 
            data.ReportDocumentValues.Add("PageCount", GlobalVar.ViolationRefNumToPrint.Count.ToString()); 

            listData.Add(data);
            i++;
        }

        XpsDocument xps = reportDocument.CreateXpsDocument(listData);
        documentViewer.Document = xps.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

        // show the elapsed time in window title
        Title += " - generated in " + (DateTime.Now - dateTimeStart).TotalMilliseconds + "ms";
```

the problem here is it give's me error like this....

[image]

Comment: Retrieve what to your list? If you mean accessing the items in your list, just iterate through it.

Comment: Retrieve it to do what? Display the values?

Comment: `ViolationRefNumToPrint[listIndex];` or iterate over it: `foreach (var vioRefNum in ViolationRefNumToPrint) { /* do something with item */ }`

Comment: why not ViolationRefNumToPrint[index]?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over it and search for the item you want.

```
foreach (string item in ViolationRefNumToPrint)
{
      Console.Out(item);
}
```

If instead you want a specific item (assume your list has objects call it `string itemImLookinFor = "some nonsense";` loop over it with a conditional to match;

```
foreach (MyObject item in ViolationRefNumToPrint)
{
      if (item.name == itemImLookinFor)
          //do something with this object
}
```